# CSI Driver: FSGroup mentioned in POD spec is not accessible from NodePublish volume

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, csi-driver, kubernetes-csi

I am using

```
 volumeMountGroup := req.GetVolumeCapability().GetMount().GetVolumeMountGroup()
 klog.V(2).Infof("-NodePublishVolume-: volumeMountGroup: %v",volumeMountGroup)
```

in my CSI NodePublishVolume method to access FSGroup mentioned in pod spec.

My Pod spec is as follows

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cos-csi-app-s3fs
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app-frontend
      image: rabbitmq
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/data"
        name: cos-csi-volume
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsGroup: 2000
    runAsUser: 2000
  volumes:
    - name: cos-csi-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
```

In the logs , empty value is printed.

```
I0321 08:42:05.845519       1 nodeserver.go:144] -NodePublishVolume-: volumeMountGroup:
```

I expected "2000". Have I missed something or is my understanding about the concept wrong.
I have added necessary capability to driver

```
 csi.NodeServiceCapability_RPC_VOLUME_MOUNT_GROUP,
```

Comment: Is this a programming question?  It seems like it would be better at the devops exchange https://devops.stackexchange.com/ or serverfault https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Check whether the CSI driver has the required permissions to access the specification of the pod,also check if it is getting invoked where it is anticipated to publish volumes.

Comment: yes @KapilSakhare Permissions look good and invocation is fine.

Comment: A driver needs to apply fsGroup at the stage step (NodeStageVolume in CSI; MountDevice in Kubernetes) instead of the mount step (NodePublishVolume in CSI; SetUp/SetUpAt in Kubernetes)

Check the "Overview" section in this [document](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/support-fsgroup.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks again @KapilSakhare. But if our driver does not require NodeStage/Unstage (This is Object Storage and doesnt attach volume to worker nodes), should we fall back to "CSI Volume fsGroup Policy" mentioned in same doc

Comment: Also spec says "// Indicates that Node service supports mounting volumes
      // with provided volume group identifier during node stage
      // or node publish RPC calls." - https://github.com/container-storage-interface/spec/blob/master/csi.proto

Comment: Try accessing the FSGroup specified in the security context directly within your CSI driver's NodePublishVolume method.

Comment: Sorry. I didnt get how this can be done. I have added code in both NodeStage and NodePublish. but throws empty value. Does this work  only  for volumes attached to worker node